# How do I perform replacement with a RegexSet?

Tags: regex, rust

Given a config file that specifies several (possibly dozens) of regular expressions, such as:

```
("2018")
authors[ ]*=[ ]*(.*)
```

I want to iterate over an input stream (line-by-line) and replace all the **captures** (in this example, all instances of "2018" and author names). The replacement depends on the capture, so the year would be replaced with "(year)" and the author name with "(author)".

### What I tried

```
extern crate regex; // 1.1.5

use regex::Regex;
use regex::RegexSet;
use std::process;
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io,
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    path::PathBuf,
};

fn main() {
    let contents = read_to_array("config.conf");
    println!("{:?}", contents);

    let set = RegexSet::new(&contents).unwrap(); // FIXME: this panics if there is an invalid regex
    println!("{:?}", set);

    let mut regexs: Vec<Regex> = Vec::new();
    for line in contents {
        let re = Regex::new(&line).unwrap(); // should not panic because we parsed Regexes above already
        regexs.push(re);
    }

    read(set, regexs);
}

fn read_to_array(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let file = File::open(filename).expect("no such file");
    let buf = BufReader::new(file);
    buf.lines()
        .map(|l| l.expect("Could not parse line"))
        .collect()
}

fn read(set: RegexSet, regexs: Vec<Regex>) {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let l = line.unwrap();
        let mut r = l.to_string();
        println!("line: {}", l);
        for idx in set.matches(&l).into_iter() {
            println!(
                "matches: {:?} - {:?} = {:?}",
                idx,
                set.patterns()[idx],
                regexs[idx]
            );
            for caps in regexs[idx].captures_iter(&l) {
                println!("captures: {:?}", caps);
                for c in caps.iter() {
                    println!("cap: {:?}", c);
                }
                r = regexs[idx].replace_all(&r, "xxx").to_string();
                println!("result: {:?}", r);
            }
        }
        println!("new line: {}", r);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50b9578e627a365b6cb40dae9b535428)

This needs `regex = "1"` in Cargo.toml, expects a config file named `config.conf` in the current directory and the data to be manipulated piped in via stdin - Cargo.toml works well for testing purposes.

### What doesn't work

`RegexSet` doesn't give me captures, so I use it to efficiently figure out if I have a match at all and then match **again** for the replacement. That strikes me as beyond clunky but is the only way I could get it to work at all.

Second, the replace always replaces the entire match, not just the captured part. That is something I don't understand and it doesn't fit to the documentation of the regex crate.

Third, iterating over the captures - and this could be the reason for #2 - always gives me the entire match at index 0, which I would like to skip. Is there something like "iterate over this, but skip the first element" in Rust?

Comment: [`Iterator::skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip)

Comment: Please make a *self-contained* [MCVE]. There's no reason to have config files or read from standard input to demonstrate your problem. Iterate over an array of strings and hard-code the configuration. These are essential steps to **minimize** your problem to the core issue.

Comment: "That strikes me as beyond clunky" -- Consider how clunky it would be if you didn't have `RegexSet` at all.